# Is Durarara SH a sequel to Durarara x2?

Tags: durarara

Is Durarara SH a sequel to Durarara X2? do I need to read Durarara X2 to understand it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Durarara SH is set 1.5 years after the end of Durarara!! A majority of the main cast returns. You probably do /have/ to have read all of Durarara to understand it, but I'd recommend it.